# Is Strawberry Perl safe?

Tags: perl, security, sha1

Strawberry Perl lists SHA1 digests on its [download page](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html).

However, looking at download page snapshots on archive.org, their SHA1 digests **for the same perl version and build** seem to change over time.

Example: in the [download page snapshot from 2013-05-10](https://web.archive.org/web/20130510201021/http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html), **strawberry-perl-5.16.3.1-32bit-portable.zip** is shown to be 86.8 MB long with an SHA1 digest of 3b9c4c32bf29e141329c3be417d9c425a7f6c2ff.

In the [download page snapshot from 2017-02-14](https://web.archive.org/web/20170214151446/http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html), the same **strawberry-perl-5.16.3.1-32bit-portable.zip** is shown to be 87.3 MB long with an SHA1 digest of 7f6da2c3e1b7a808f27969976777f47a7a7c6544.

And on the [current download page](http://strawberryperl.com/releases.html), the same **strawberry-perl-5.16.3.1-32bit-portable.zip** is shown to be 91.0 MB long with an SHA1 digest of 00ba29e351e2f74a7dbceaad5d9bc20159dd7003

I thought they might have recompiled the package for some reason, but the current **strawberry-perl-5.10.0.6-portable.zip** has only one file dated later than 2009 (it's **portable.perl**), so this doesn't explain why the archive grew over time. Sadly, I don't have older zip files, so I have no way of knowing what changed inside the archive.

What's going on here? Why do **past** builds change over time?? I am kind of concerned that some hackers might be injecting malicious code or something into binary perl packages...

Is there a rational explanation here ? Thanks...

Comment: Re "*so this doesn't explain why the archive grew over time*", Sure it does. It means the archived had to be recreated in part or in whole. Different compressors will result in different sizes. And modifying the archive is probably less space-efficient than recreating it from scratch. The only mystery is why they didn't bump the version numbers. Anyway, it's all open-source, so feel free to compare the files in the distribution against their originals

Answer (score 0):

An hash such as a SHA1 digest is good to defend against communication errors, that is to ensure integrity of what you downloaded (basically proving: "file on your hard disk" = "file on the webserver"), but just by itself does not help to ensure authentication.

For that, files should be signed with some PGP signature, or using X.509 certificates. This is the only way you could verify that the file was indeed **produced** by the true intended authors.

So just by itself your observation neither signal an attack nor helps you defend against one in fact.

Like @ikegami said, you can even configure compressors with a different RAM/time ratio and the same on will produce different results.

See for example in Unix `zip`:

```
   -Z cm
   --compression-method cm
          Set the default compression method.  Currently the main methods supported by zip are store and deflate.  Compression method can be set to:

          store - Setting the compression method to store forces zip to store entries with no compression.  This is generally faster than compressing entries, but results in no space savings.  This is the same as using -0 (compression level zero).

          deflate - This is the default method for zip.  If zip determines that storing is better than deflation, the entry will be stored instead.

          bzip2 - If bzip2 support is compiled in, this compression method also becomes available.  Only some modern unzips currently support the bzip2 compression method, so test the unzip you will be using before relying on archives using this method (compression method 12).
```

and

```
   -#
   (-0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9)
          Regulate the speed of compression using the specified digit #, where -0 indicates no compression (store all files), -1 indicates the fastest compression speed (less compression) and -9 indicates the slowest compression speed (optimal compression, ignores the suffix list). The default compression level is -6.

          Though still being worked, the intention is this setting will control compression speed for all compression methods.  Currently only deflation is controlled.
```

The same source code could have been recompressed over time when the website is regenerated. So same content but different archive results.

I have downloaded all three files. In fact they are the same sizes exactly (or the WayBack machine did not store them correctly, it does not do a redirection), and all in fact with a SHA1 hash of `00ba29e351e2f74a7dbceaad5d9bc20159dd7003`.

Your best bet is probably to ask StrawberryPerl organization directly.